# Store value in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

i have one column in excel wherein there are list of values.

what i want to do is i want to remove duplicate values from that column and want to store all that unique values in one cell 
e.g. after removeing the duplicates if there are list of below values
OPF
OIP
OWL
OVL
Then i want to store above details in one cell i.e. OPF,OIP,OWL,OVL

Please help...it will be good if there will be any vba code or excel formula

[image: Sample]

Comment: `Please help...it will be good if there will be any vba code or excel formula` It will be good if I could get paid for these kind of questions :D You may want to see [How To Ask Good Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code writing service but we will be happy to help you with yours.  Show us what you have tried and where you have run into problems.  There are plenty of examples of similar problems on SO that should give you a start. You might start by checking Excel HELP for `remove duplicates`, then search SO for how to concatenate a variable number of cells into one.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all help...

I done with my own.....however really thanks for the same...

```
Sub combine()
Dim mstr, mstr2 As String
Dim v As Range
Set v = Sheets("Data").Range("A1")
mstr = ""
mstr2 = ""
i = 0
Do
i = i + 1
v.Cells(i, 1).Select

If IsNumeric(v.Cells(i, 1)) = True Then
mstr = mstr + "'" + str(v.Cells(i, 1)) + "'  or "
mstr2 = mstr2 + "'" + str(v.Cells(i, 1)) + "'  , "
Else
mstr = mstr + "'" + v.Cells(i, 1) + "'  or "
mstr2 = mstr2 + "" + v.Cells(i, 1) + "  , "
End If

Loop While IsEmpty(v.Cells(i + 1)) = False
mstr = Left(mstr, Len(mstr) - 4)
mstr2 = Left(mstr2, Len(mstr2) - 4)
Sheets("Data").Range("C3") = mstr
Sheets("Data").Range("C4") = mstr2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following custom function:

```
Function UniqueInString(InputList As Range) As String

    Dim inputListArray() As String

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim size As Integer
    size = 0
    ReDim Preserve inputListArray(size)
    For Each cell In InputList.Cells
        If Not (UBound(Filter(inputListArray, cell.Value)) > -1) Then
            ReDim Preserve inputListArray(size)
            inputListArray(size) = cell.Value
            size = size + 1
        End If
    Next cell


    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim result As String
    result = ""
    For counter = 0 To UBound(inputListArray)
        result = result + inputListArray(counter) + ","
    Next counter
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    UniqueInString = result
End Function
```

This wil give you the unique records in one cell, without having to create the unique records list. Just call this function on the list containing all records. Note that I do not thing this would perform that well if there where very many records.